# html5 tags are not working in phonegap-android

Tags: cordova

I am trying to use the html5 slider tag in my phonegap application. But the slider is not displaying on the Android emulator. I am using phonegap.0.9.4, android 2.2. Can anyone please tell me how to make html5 tags work in my application?

thanks in advance..

Comment: so how did u solve this problem? I've tried on an android tablet, not simulator and I can only see the bar of the slider not the sliding button as well. I use just html5 range input - no jQuery.(I have <!DOCTYPE html> tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it returning your input as a "text" type input?  The "range" type for input elements in HTML5 is likely not supported in the browser.  You can try using jQuery's slider: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

Comment: My code is...<html><head> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.4.js"></script></head> <body> <input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" /> <span id="range">0</span> <script type="text/javascript"> function showValue(newValue) { document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue; } </script> </body> </html> ..The slider is not displaying..but in safari browser it is displaying..I tried with the code shown in http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/ it is also not working..

Comment: Like I said, the "range" input is likely not supported in the emulator's browser.  I find it unlikely that the jQuery slider doesn't work, unless somehow your emulator is hosed.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you're trying to access device-specific functionality (GPS, camera, etc), the code you create for PhoneGap should be testable using a browser. Can you verify that your HTML is functioning properly in a browser, prior to testing it with the Android emulator?

If your code successfully runs in a browser, but fails to do so in the Android emulator... sharing the problematic code may help others pinpoint the source of your problem. Otherwise, no one will respond because there's nothing specific they can respond to.

Comment: My code is...<html>
<body>
<input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" />
<span id="range">0</span>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showValue(newValue)
{
 document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue;
}
</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: My code is...<html><head> <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap.0.9.4.js"></script></head> <body> <input type="range" min="0" max="50" value="0" step="5" onchange="showValue(this.value)" /> <span id="range">0</span> <script type="text/javascript"> function showValue(newValue) { document.getElementById("range").innerHTML=newValue; } </script> </body> </html> ..The slider is not displaying..but in safari browser it is displaying

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> i didnt use this.Thats why it didn't work.In jquerymobile it is worked fine.